# Cannot enable App Check for Cloud Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-app-check

I have a Cloud Firestore configured and would like to secure this with App Check. The problem is that App Check does not recognize that Firestore is running. It still says "Start using Cloud Firestore to enable App Check".

Does anyone know how to fix this? I am using the Firestore database with my Flutter app. I have already configured the app in Firebase and in App Check.

I added the Firestore database and the registered my Flutter app in Firebase. Then I registered my app with the signatures to App Check. I expected to be able to enable App Check for Firestore, but I can't.